# Website wont scroll only on android devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

While trying to develop a website for a friend, I found out that it would not scroll on android devices, but It does scroll on iphones, ipads, windows phones, etc... I have already checked for body overflow:hidden but that does not seem to solve the problem. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance for your time!
Here is the link: http://www.ifcinternationaltrade.com/CesarCuadros/index.html

Comment: The carousel is capturing the touch. If you jump to a page without, it scrolls as expected. This looks similar: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2040

Comment: please add your code here on stackoverflow, rather than pasting a link to code. Your code may be long, but a minimal code example, enough to replicate the problem, will do

Comment: @RachelGallen OP poted a link to a whole deployed site. How on earth would you test better on android just having a snippet here? Having the original code is far better even if off-site...

Comment: @ZorgoZ I didn't follow link. Links break, that's why code should be posted on SO

Comment: @RachelGallen that might be true, still, there are cases where this is the only feasible approach. This is one. You either want to keep a bunch of code snippets or help people. Sometimes you can do both - sometimes not. But _you_ decide which is more important from your point of view.

Comment: Read How to Ask page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ZorgoZ Thanks!!! This solved my problem.